# Why prescaler doesn't give 50% duty cycle pulse

Tags: microcontroller, avr, clock, duty-cycle

I am new to embedded electronics. While reading the datasheet of ATmega328P, I saw this when timers and their timing diagrams were given...  I wonder why clk/8 is not of 50% duty cycle...Please help me in understanding the reason behind it...[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're only showing half the diagram there, and you're completely missing the context.  Let me show you the whole diagram:

[image]

And then you have the context for the diagram:

> The following figures show the Timer/Counter in synchronous mode, and the timer clock (\$clk_{T2}\$ ) is therefore shown as a clock enable signal.

So this is a counter, yes?  Ok.  So it counts up every time the incoming clock toggles.

Now, you could then pass that incoming clock through another counter block as a prescaler and then attach your counting up to that.  That gets complex though, with various multiplexers and such, and it's also very inefficient on power, since there is a *lot* of switching going on there.

So instead a technique called [Clock Gating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_gating) is used.

The counter is still connected to the main incoming clock, and it counts up every time it sees that clock toggle.  However now, because of the clock gating, it only sees every 8th cycle.

If you had a 50% duty cycle then your counter would count up rapidly at \$clk_{IO}\$ for half the prescaler period, and then not count up at all for the other half.  So it would be like:

```
0 1 2 3 . . . . 4 5 6 7 . . . . 8 9 (etc)
```

Which really isn't what you want.  So the gate signal has to be 1 clock cycle in width, which gives you:

```
0 . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . 2 . (etc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking only on the diagram provided, the logic can be derived as follows: Generate a pulse with width equal to a main clock period every 8 main clock cycles. This logic can be generated by a simple 8-counter, which will generate the output signal each time it's value is overflows. It is a very simple solution, so lacking the requirement to have 50% duty cycle it will be sufficient.

Comment: Clock signal's 50% duty cycle, because it gives equal time for any operations happening at raising or trailing edge of a pulse... but then what's the need for clk/8 not to be a 50% duty cycle..that is, this clock pulse gives unequal weightage for any operation getting triggered at the edges...

Comment: Even if the signal is not 50% duty cycle, you still have equal time between rising edges and the falling edges. So the only difference will be if you want to time your logic on both rising and falling edges, which is generally not a so good idea.